# Array of Gauges with angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gauge

I am using gauge.js(http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/) on my angular.js and I am trying to create dynamic instans of gauges, with settings value throw ng-model,
I have in my template:

```
  <a ng-repeat="item in items" 
           href="#/{{item.queId}}"
           class="item item-thumbnail-left">
          <img ng-src="{{ item.entrancePhotoUrl }}">
          <h1>{{ item.name }}</h1><h5>{{item.waitTimeEstimationSec}}</h5>
          <h4>{{ item.streetAddress }}</h4>
          <canvas gaugejs options="gaugeOptions" value="12" max-value="15" animation-time="animationTime"></canvas>
        </a>
      </div>
```

but still how can I set values for my gauge with ng model?

thanks!

Comment: canvas does not get updates as the values change in angularjs. you should remove the old canvas and create a new one

Comment: how can I set values woth ng models on gauge on the load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best gauge for me and its wj-radial-gauge. very easy to use.